# Alignment Shiny images

Tags: shiny

Apee seems straightforward but I get a huge hole between rows, guessing that size aligns so that all rows become the height of the biggest image. How could I change all that?

mainPanel(
fluidRow(
column(
4,
textOutput("eim")
),  column
(4,
textOutput("cim")
),
column(
4,
textOutput("bim")
)),

```
  fluidRow(
    column(4,imageOutput('photo1')
    ), column 
    (4,
      imageOutput('photo2',brush=brushOpts(id="pbtwo",delay=0),click="p2click")
    ), column 
    (4,
      imageOutput('photo3',brush=brushOpts(id="pbthree"))
    )),
fluidRow(
```

column(
4,align="top",
imageOutput("pr1"),
),
column
(4,
imageOutput("pr2")
), column
(4,
imageOutput("pr3")
)),
fluidRow(
column(
4,
textOutput('xa1'),
),
column
(4,
textOutput("xa2")
), column
(4,
imageOutput("xa3")
)),
fluidRow(
column
(4,
plotOutput('xaione')

```
    ), column 
    (4,
      plotOutput('sim')
    ),
    column 
    (4,
      plotOutput('xaitwo')
    ))
))
```

)